# Split many multi-band files into single-band files using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, extract, multi-band

I wanted to know how to take many multi-band (RGB) files in a folder and extract a single band from each one, putting everything in an output folder with the single band transformed files.

How should I proceed without extracting every single file?

Comment: IMHO you can approach any single step instead of a complete application. Any single step already documented in SE

Comment: btw do you ned pyqgis or just create a agis batch process suing processing or a processing model?

Comment: No, I did not create any pyqgis scripts yet, but I was looking in the forum and I found a lot of confusion.
Can you help me?

Comment: According to the rules of this website, if you're asking for help with coding you must include a coding attempt. Therefore this question will be closed as off-topic. You can make it it eligible for re-opening by [edit]ing the question to either (1) include a coding attempt, or (2) request a non-coded solution.